# Not able to create a Registry key in Hkey_Local_Machine from Excel with UAC on

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have an excel application(this application is like a product to our company) for which i have created licensing process using Excel & VBA. When the user registers the application using a product key, an entry will be created in Registry and the same will be validated each time the application gets opened. I used the win-API function and VBA to create the key as shown below.

```vb
Result = RegCreateKeyEx(HKey:=HKLM, lpSubKey:=SubKeyName, Reserved:=0&, lpClass:=vbNullString, _
                dwOptions:=REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, samDesired:=KEY_ALL_ACCESS, _
                lpSecurityAttributes:=SecAttrib, phkResult:=HKey, lpdwDisposition:=Disposition)
```

This product licensing should work for all the users in the local machine. So i am saving the product key in the Registry under HKey_Local_Machine. But with UAC on, i am not able to read from/write to Registry though the user has admin privileges. I always get the error code 5(access denied). Read/write to HKey_Current_User works fine though, but this is not an option in my case as the product registration has to work for all the users on local machine. If i lower the UAC to Never_Notify_Me then read/write to HKLM works fine.

what i tried:

1. I tried to run excel application as an administrator(Excel->Properties->Run this program as administrator). Read/write to Registry HKLM works, but i am not able to open excel application if excel is not already open, meaning by double clicking on the application. Got the error "There was a problem sending the command to the program". So clients will not accept this solution.
2. I have created a C# dotnet dll for writing to the registry and added an application manifest to it with the following info to make it UAC aware.

```xml
<security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
          <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

This works fine, when i use it as an exe(by default exe runs as an administrator), but the moment i convert it to COM visible dll and add to Excel references and try to create the registry key, it says access denied.

1. Created a RegistrySecurity Object in C# and gave the read,write privileges as shown below. But same access denied issue comes up.

```c
   RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
    rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user, 
        RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey| RegistryRights.Delete, 
        InheritanceFlags.None, 
        PropagationFlags.None, 
        AccessControlType.Allow));
```

1. Did google search to see if there is a WIN-API which allows me to read/write to registry by wither lowering the UAC level temporarily or by somehow bypassing it. But no luck here too.

Now can someone please guide me on how i can make my way through this situation. I am looking for a solution using C# dotnet dll or any other work around like solving excel - run as admin issue. 
-highly appreciate any suggestions..

Comment: Dll aren't programs so UAC irrelevent to a DLL, it getssecurity from the client program. There is no feature that says, "please turn off security for my virus". Excel cannot write where it's not allowed.

Comment: +1 for well written question. The only way around this in Excel is actually lowering the UAC settings to "never notify me" otherwise it won't work. That's as far as I am concerned but maybe someone actually knows a work-around I would be interested in seeing it too

Comment: There is no workaround for Viruses to bypass UAC. There are things that can be configured (eg turn UAC off), you can host the reg code in a admin security context (an COM exe server or Service). But they all require an admin password at some stage. The central approach is flawed. He is doing exactly the same as a Virus would. He want to  write to a system area without a password. Admins are the only people that can install software for All Users.

Comment: Dear Noodles and dear me_how, Thanks so much for the analysis. Well, then i guess i have to write to HKey_CurrentUser and install the application for one login-account at a time. Please add your comments as answer, i'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not possible to bypass UAC and write product key to HKey_Local_Machine with UAC security level is set to high, now i am writing the product key information to HKey_CurrentUser in registry. 
Even if the UAC security level is set to high, we can read and write to HKey_CurrentUser using VBA & Win-API . But the drawback of this method is my application's product key needs to be written to HKey_CurrentUser for each of the login-accounts one at a time, if the application is required to run in all the login-accounts on given system. 
Thanks all for the help.